# Incorrect entry in file from linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list

This is the one of main part of the code that the pls format file should convert to m3u format song under numbers of seconds which specified :

```
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=3
File1=C:\muzika\Chris Rea - Looking For The Summer.mp3
Title1=Chris Rea - Looking For The Summer
Length1=302
File2=C:\muzika\Simply Red - Holding Back The Years.mp3
Title2=Simply Red - Holding Back The Years
Length2=265
File3=C:\muzika\Mambo Kings - Luz de luna.mp3
Title3=Mambo Kings - Luz de luna
Length3=207
Version=2
```

convert to:

```
#EXTINF:207,Mambo Kings - Luz de luna
C:\muzika\Mambo Kings - Luz de luna.mp3
#EXTINF:265,Simply Red - Holding Back The Years
C:\muzika\Simply Red - Holding Back The Years.mp3
```

.

```
if ( file != NULL )
{
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            int j=0;
            if (line[0] == 'F') {
                int brojac=6;
                while(line[brojac]!='\n'){
                    ffolder[j]=line[brojac];
                    j++;
                    brojac++;
                }
                folder=ffolder;



            }
            if (line[0] == 'T') {
                int brojac=7;
                while(line[brojac]!='\n'){
                    naslov1[j]=line[brojac];
                    j++;
                    brojac++;
                }
                naslov=naslov1;



            }
            if (line[0] == 'L') {
                int brojac=8;
                while(line[brojac]!='\n'){
                    vremee[j]=line[brojac];
                    j++;
                    brojac++;
                }
                vreme=vremee;
                //intvreme = folder11(line);
                if(atoi(vremee)<atoi(argv[3])) {
                    //fprintf(out, "\n#EXTINF:%s,%s\n%s", vremee,naslov1,ffolder);**key part**
                    struct pesma *link = (struct pesma *) malloc(sizeof(struct pesma));
                    link->folder = folder;
                    printf("%s\n",folder);
                    link->naslov = naslov;
                    printf("%s\n",naslov);
                    link->vreme = atoi(vreme);
                    link->next = NULL;
                    if (!glava) {
                        glava = link;
                    } else {
                        struct pesma *tail = glava;
                        while (tail->next) {
                            tail = tail->next;
                        }
                        tail->next = link;
                    }
                }
            }




        }

        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

When I call the function that should print the elements of the linked list, for each song that meets the criteria, print this:

```
#EXTINF:207,Mambo Kings - Luz de luna
C:\muzika\Mambo Kings - Luz de luna.mp3
#EXTINF:265,Mambo Kings - Luz de luna
C:\muzika\Mambo Kings - Luz de luna.mp3
```

vreme is normal,but folder and naslov are from last last line in file.

However, if I use the fprintf function (in the key part in the main code) instead of a concatenated list, the printout is correct, but then I can't sort alphabetically.

```
fprintf(out, "\n#EXTINF:%s,%s\n%s", vremee,naslov1,ffolder);
```

I'm wondering why the linked list is printed like this?

Comment: `char line[256];` <<-- all substrings point into this single buffer. Only the last one remains, the rest is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

my guess - cant do better since we have an incomplete program

```
link->folder = folder;
```

link is a char * member. If so you should do

```
link->folder = strdup(folder);
```

otherwise they all end up pointing to the buffer 'folder' and whatever it last contained

Answer (score 0):

Your application modified so that it reads the input data into a linked list. Using `char` arrays in the song struct makes them easier to handle. For sorting the list insertion sort is used.

There remains some work to do with this code:

- Extract duplicate code into functions
- Complete error handling, a.o. check all function return values
- Maybe use a command line argument for the input file name

In general, try to use English words for names (data structures, functions, variables, etc.).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 256

typedef struct song { // pesma
    char file[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char title[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]; // naslov
    int time; // vreme
    struct song * next;
} SONG;

// Insertion Sort
SONG * sort_songs(SONG * root) {
    if (root == NULL || root->next == NULL) {
        // All lists with less than two elements are already sorted.
        return root;
    }

    // put first element into sorted list
    SONG * sorted_root = root;

    // start iteration with second element
    SONG * iterator = root->next;

    // set end of sorted list
    sorted_root->next = NULL;

    while (iterator != NULL) {
        // trace position directly before insertion point
        SONG * previous = NULL;
        // iterate over already sorted list
        SONG * sorted_iterator = sorted_root;
        // determine insertion point in already sorted list
        while (
            // list end not reached
            sorted_iterator != NULL
            &&
            // need to advance in sorted list for proper position
            strcmp(sorted_iterator->title, iterator->title) <= 0) {
            previous = sorted_iterator;
            sorted_iterator = sorted_iterator->next;
        }
        if (previous == NULL) {
            // prepend sorted list with element
            SONG * tmp = sorted_root;
            sorted_root = iterator;
            iterator = iterator->next;
            sorted_root->next = tmp;
        } else if (sorted_iterator == NULL) {
            // append new last element in sorted list
            previous->next = iterator;
            SONG * tmp = iterator->next;
            iterator->next = NULL;
            iterator = tmp;
        } else {
            // insert element at correct position
            SONG * tmp = iterator->next;
            previous->next = iterator;
            iterator->next = sorted_iterator;
            iterator = tmp;                
        }
    }
    return sorted_root;
}

int main()
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char *filename = "playlist.txt";

    // pointer to first element of the linked song list
    SONG *root = NULL; // glava

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'!\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read line containing "[playlist]"
    fgets(line, sizeof line, file);

    // read line containing "NumberOfEntries=3"
    fgets(line, sizeof line, file);
    char *start_position = strchr(line, '=') + 1;
    int number_of_entries = atoi(start_position);
    printf("Number of entries: %d\n", number_of_entries);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_entries; i++) {
        // allocate new node for linked list and put it to the front of the list
        SONG *node = malloc(sizeof(SONG));
        node->next = root;
        root = node;

        // read file name
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file!\n");
            fclose(file);
            // TODO: release allocated memory
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        start_position = strchr(line, '=') + 1;
        strcpy(node->file, start_position);
        node->file[strlen(start_position) - 1] = '\0';

        // read title
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file!\n");
            fclose(file);
            // TODO: release allocated memory
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        start_position = strchr(line, '=') + 1;
        strcpy(node->title, start_position);
        node->title[strlen(start_position) - 1] = '\0';

        // read time
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file!\n");
            fclose(file);
            // TODO: release allocated memory
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        start_position = strchr(line, '=') + 1;
        int time = atoi(start_position);
        node->time = time;
    }

    // read version
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file!\n");
        fclose(file);
        // TODO: release allocated memory
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    start_position = strchr(line, '=') + 1;
    int version = atoi(start_position);
    printf("Version: %d\n", version);

    root = sort_songs(root);

    SONG * iterator = root;
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "\n#EXTINF:%d,%s\n%s", iterator->time, iterator->title, iterator->file);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");

    // free the allocated memory
    while (root != NULL) {
        SONG * next = root->next;
        free(root);
        root = next;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall convert_playlist.c
$ ./a.out                     
Number of entries: 3
Version: 2

#EXTINF:302,Chris Rea - Looking For The Summer
C:\muzika\Chris Rea - Looking For The Summer.mp3
#EXTINF:207,Mambo Kings - Luz de luna
C:\muzika\Mambo Kings - Luz de luna.mp3
#EXTINF:265,Simply Red - Holding Back The Years
C:\muzika\Simply Red - Holding Back The Years.mp3
$
```